# WebStorm change single quotes to double when there is an apostrophe when commit

Tags: angular, webstorm, prettier-eslint

After I commit a file, my IDE WebStorm changes the string `'We can\’t'` to `"We can’t"` How can I prevent this ?

I already do Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> TypeScript -> Punctuation
And put 'single' quotes 'always'

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Prettier for code reformatting? when being configured to use single quotes, it tends to minimize escaping, changing single quotes to double in such cases, see https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3804#issuecomment-359961713